# setInterval is not working correct with Load More script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on Ajax,Right now i am fetching data from database suceessfully with "Load More" functionality
Means My data is displaying correctly after scroll down,But now i want to call function after every 10 seconds
But its giving me "wrong data",Means records are not fetching properly
Here is my current code

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var limit = 7;
      var start = 0;
      var action = 'inactive';
      function lazzy_loader(limit)
        {
              var output = '';
              for(var count=0; count<limit; count++)
              {
                output += '<div class="post_data">';
                output += '<p><span class="content-placeholder" style="width:100%; height: 30px;">&nbsp;</span></p>';
                output += '<p><span class="content-placeholder" style="width:100%; height: 100px;">&nbsp;</span></p>';
                output += '</div>';
              }
              $('#load_data_message').html(output);
        }
    lazzy_loader(limit);
function load_data(limit, start)
    {
        var wallet_address="<?php echo $WalletAddress; ?>";
     $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>Main/fetch",
        method:"POST",
        data:{limit:limit, start:start,wallet_address:wallet_address},
        cache: false,
        success:function(data)
        {
          if(data.trim()=='')
          {
            $('#load_data_message').html('<h3>No More Result Found</h3>');
            action = 'active';
          }
          else
          {
            $('#load_data').html("");
            $('#load_data').append(data);
            $('#load_data_message').html("");
            action = 'inactive';
          }
        }
     })
    }   
            
    if(action == 'inactive')
    {
      action = 'active';
      load_data(limit, start);
    }

    $(window).scroll(function(){
      if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive')
      {
        lazzy_loader(limit);
        action = 'active';
        start = start + limit;
        setTimeout(function(){
          load_data(limit, start);
        }, 1000);
      }
    });
    
});
</script>
```

And for call function after 10 seconds i added following function,but data is not fetching in correctly,Means random data showing
Where i am wrong ?

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive')
      {
        var limit = 7;
        var start = 0;
        action = 'active';
        load_data(limit, start);
      } 
        
}, 10000);
```

Comment: The code does not output the string "wrong data" anywhere. Can you clarify your problem, and share your attempts to resolve the problem?

Comment: If you indent your code in a more consistent manner, it will be much easier to read it and follow the flow.

Comment: I presume that "wrong data" is a message from the server side response, so you'll have to check the php code. I also observe that the `limit` and `start` vars are not increasing anywhere so you're sending the same parameters everytime. Also any invalid response must be checked in the `$WalletAddress` php code. Use your browser code inspector to monitor the network traffic and analyze the request and response data of each request.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: Actually all things is done except set interval , "Wrong data" means fetching random data, it seems like something wrong with my function which i created for setinterval

Comment: @TommyBlackbird: Php code is fine and working properly, Something wrong with my code which i created for setinterval, kindly check my function and tell me is this right or not

Comment: You tagged the wrong person. All I said was that you should indent your code more consistently to make it more readable. However, you need to be way more specific than just saying "wrong data". We have no idea what that means in reality, which makes it very hard to have a clue where or why it goes wrong. What debugging have you done? We can't test your code for you to debug it. You need to do that for us and then tell us the _specifics_ of your findings.

Comment: "it seems like something wrong with my function"  - what have you tried to debug that? If the backend provides the proper data, how could the given JS code mess that up?

Comment: @NicoHaase: if i remove "setinterval" function then everything is working fine but because i am new in javascript so i copy "scroll function" and pass static limit start

Comment: *Is* it random data?  Or is it always the first 7 records?

Comment: @freedomn-m: you are right always first 7 records, kindly give me solution and tell me where i am wrong ?

Comment: As pointed out earlier, you have `var start = 0;` *inside* your `setInterval` - so it always gets records from 0.  You need a variable *outside* the setInterval that records "previous start" so you can do: `load_data(limit, start); start+=limit;`

Comment: @freedomn-m: can you write exact/correct code please so i can check in my side

Comment: `var start = 0;setInterval(function() { start+=7; load_data(7, start); }, 10000);`